# How close is $n $ to $ n \log n$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algorithms, asymptotics, self-learning

How close is $n $ to $ n \log n$?

I know $\mathcal{O}(n) < \mathcal{O}(n \log n)$

But for some small $\epsilon > 0 , n^{1+\epsilon}=n \log n$. How much small is that $\epsilon$? The reason why i got this doubt is when i was thinking to last case of master theorem $T(n)=aT(n/b) + f(n)$ namely - f(n) is logarithmically larger or asymptotically equal to $n^{\log_b a}$

Comment: For every $\epsilon>0,\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{1+\epsilon}}{n\log n}\to\infty$ i.e. $n^{1+\epsilon}$ grows faster asymptotically than $n\log n$ for all $\epsilon>0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, $\log n = n^{\log_n \log n} = n^{\frac{\log \log n}{\log n}}$, so $\epsilon = \frac{\log \log n}{\log n}$.

I think the important takeaway from this is that $\epsilon$ is smaller than any constant as $n \to \infty$, since $\log\log n \ll \log n$.

Answer (score 3):

For any $\epsilon > 0$, $n^{1+\epsilon}$ grows faster than $n \log n$ (in the sense that $\frac{n^{1+\epsilon}}{n \log n} \to \infty$).

Answer (score 1):

This is an important, iconic example, turning up in many places.

To my mind, since one-way-or-another we know that $f(x) = {\log x\over x^\varepsilon}\to 0$ as $x\to +\infty$, the questions of where the maximum occurs, and what it is, are natural.

And, as it happens, the computation is accessible in human terms. Namely, look for a critical point $x_o$, that is, where $f'(x_o)=0$. This condition is
$$
0\;=\;{1\over x}{1\over x^\varepsilon}-\varepsilon\cdot {\log x\over x^{\varepsilon+1}}
\;=\; {1-\varepsilon\cdot \log x \over x^{\varepsilon+1}}
$$
Thus, the maximum occurs where $\log x = 1/\varepsilon$. The value is easy to figure out, also.

Comment: sir here we are calculating max value of log x / x^e. Limit tending to zero means even for smaller smaller value of e, log x is smaller. I want that what value of e makes log x and x^e equal. But it turns out what ever i pick e value(>0) log x value turns out to be still smaller. But what you wrote is max of f(x) which means at what x, log x/x^e is max(e constant). This is something different right. Pls correct if  i am wrong.

Comment: By the way sir i love your abstract algebra course notes. I use it for my reference. THanks for the nice work.

Comment: @Srinivas, I'm glad my algebra notes are useful to you! But/and a point about your question: my comparison of $\log x$ and $x^\varepsilon$ was for _all_ real $x>0$. That is, we can find an explicit $x_o$ beyond which $x^\varepsilon$ is larger than $\log x$, for fixed $\varepsilon$. As a variation, if you are given $x_o$, you can find the corresponding $\varepsilon$ by looking at the same equation (for the critical point).

Comment: Understood now sir. Nice approach. But on the other side, are we splitting the hair. Already f(x) goes to 0 at x tends to infinity. We obviously get some value of infinity for x when log x = x^e (e fixed). log x = 1/e (e very small means x = infinity right?).

Comment: @Srinivas, well, it's perhaps more precise to talk about "limits" than literal "arrival at limits". But it's a matter of taste and perception, for sure. It is possible to make use of infinitesimals completely rigorous (not only useful, as Euler showed), as Abraham Robinson, Ed Nelson, and others have shown... :)

Comment: I understood what you were refering sir. Thank you for the nice thought process.